# ggplot - how to make errorbar with respect to gender

Tags: r, ggplot2

Few words at the beginning - I have just started my journey with R, and after initial experience am really keen on further learning! But I've encountered a huge problem and searching in google doesnt seem to help. Maybe some good soul here could guide me with your wisdom :)

So, I've been trying to make an error_bar in R, using ggplot. But the problem is that on y axis I got continuous variable (marital satisfaction), x ais is factor (consisting of three levels), and I also wanted to add gender to the plot (what is more, all of it has to be black-white, which makes it double).

What I want to do is to show the means and standard deviation of marital satisfaction in three different religions (Christian, Muslim, atheistic) with respect to gender (male, female). Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance! <3

I've already tried doing boxplot with my data, but such plot doesnt provide with any useful information, and after googling I think this error bar would better fit into the data.
Here how it looks like:

```
factor(ds$`Religion`, levels = c(2, 4, 6), labels = c("Christian", "Muslim", "atheistic"))
factor(ds$Sex, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Male", "Female"))

obj1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(y=Marital, x=factor(Religion), fill=factor(Sex))) + geom_boxplot()

obj1+labs(x="Religious affiliation", y="Marital satisfaction", fill="Sex") -> obj2
obj2 + scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Christian','Muslim','atheistic')) -> obj3
obj3 + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Sex", labels = c("Male", "Female")) -> obj4
obj4 + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 1)) -> obj5
```

I copy pasted my data here:
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2l4k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is to show the means and standard deviation of marital satisfaction in three different religions (Christian, Muslim, atheistic) with respect to gender (male, female). Do you have any idea how to do it?

The simple answer to this question is that you should create the summary statistics beforehand. After that picking the visualization becomes trivial.

Assuming you are interested in using a tidyverse solution I would proceed as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
ds %>%
group_by(Religion, Sex) %>%
summarize(meanVal = mean(Marital),
          sdVal = sd(Marital)) -> ds.summarized
```

`ds.summarized`will have one row for each Religion-Sex combination and provides the mean and the sd of martial satisfaction in this group. You can then proceed plotting using `geom_errorbar` where with aesthetics `y=meanVal`, `ymin=meanVal - sdVal` and `ymax=meanVal + sdVal`. One final remark - you may want to use standard errors instead of standard deviation.